# How to validate IP Address in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to validate ip address using MVC 3. If user entered wrong ip address then page should show "wrong ip address message" to user. I searched a lot on internet but didnt get proper solution.
Can you please help me...
Thanks in advance.

Code For Model:

```
 [Display(Name = "EQ")]
    public string EQ { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "EQD")]
    public string EQD { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "BFX")]
    public string BFX { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLB")]
    public string SLB { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Others")]
    public string Others { get; set; }
```

I want seperate 5 check boxes i.e. (EQ, EQD, BFX, SLB and Others).

Code of View:

```
<div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EQ)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.EQ)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EQ)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EQD)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.EQD)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EQD)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BFX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.BFX)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BFX)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SLB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.SLB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SLB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label" style="font-weight: bold">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Others)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Others)*@
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Model => Model.Others)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Others)
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you use Regex?

Comment: you want ip address format validation?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using **IPAddress.TryParse()**

> Determines whether a string is a valid IP address.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: TryParse will return "True" for cases you may not expect (such as the integer "1" by itself).

Answer (score 1):

In your model

[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$")]

public string AssignedIP { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a great method for MVC
https://codingjourneyman.com/2015/01/08/model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc/

```
public class IPAddressModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [IpAddress]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Your IP address")]
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
}
```